# How to select current date from SQLite using ormlite?

Tags: java, jdbc, ormlite

Is there a way to execute custom query `SELECT date('now');` while using **ormlite**? Or this is only possible to turn to underlying `sqlite xerial jdbc driver` directly?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to execute custom query SELECT date('now'); while using ormlite?

This is the sort of call that is very database specific.  You can, however use the [`dao.queryRaw(...) method`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.html#queryRaw(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)) method which returns the results as a `String[]`.  See the [documentation on raw queries](http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries).

Something like this should work:

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults = dao.queryRaw("SELECT date('now')");
String[] results = rawResults.getResults().get(0);
System.out.println("now date = " + results[0]);
```